# News 3.0.1 - custom templates

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

Since I upgraded to Typo3 6.+, I've had a lot of hard times to get my custom templates/partials to work under a **custom extension extended from News 3.0.1**.

Of course I ran through the documentation : http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/stable/singlehtml/#changing-paths-of-the-template

But I don't get it, I tried to use the typoscript from the documentation into my setup and constants, but I can't get it to work --> the default templates/partials from ext:news are the ones that show up all the time.

Here is my Configuration (setup) :

```
lib.cust_news= COA
   lib.cust_news{
     20 = TEXT
     20.wrap = <div>

     30 = USER
     30{
          userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
          extensionName = News
          pluginName = Pi1

          switchableControllerActions {
            News {
                   1 = list
             }
          }

          view {
              templateRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/myExt/Templates/
              partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/myExt/Partials/
              layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/myExt/Layouts/
           }

           settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
           settings {
              startingpoint = 9
              limit = 5
           }
      }

     40 = TEXT
     40.wrap = </div>
 }
```

This code worked for me in the past with previous versions of News and Typo3, now I just don't get it.

Any help of some sort would be very much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 3.0.0, EXT:news is using the `layoutRootPaths`, `templateRootPaths` and `partialRootPaths` instead of their singular variant. This enables you to only copy and modify the templates you really need to change instead of copying all. Have a look at the [default settings](https://git.typo3.org/TYPO3CMS/Extensions/news.git/blob/0afa4f653afa12359b9a767fee5ed143ded2ae61:/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt#l8).

So your configuration should respect the new default configuration:

```
view {
  templateRootPaths.200 = fileadmin/templates/ext/myExt/Templates/
  partialRootPaths.200 = fileadmin/templates/ext/myExt/Partials/
  layoutRootPaths.200 = fileadmin/templates/ext/myExt/Layouts/
}
```

EXT:news uses the key 100, so if you use anything greater than 100, your templates will have priority.